# Customize JAXB 2.0 generated method names from a xsd:choice element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to figure out how to customize a method name that's being generated by JAXB 2.1.12. I have an epic XML schema (that is not in my control), and it contains a group with a choice element that contains about 200 other elements. So when I'm generating the JAXB classes, the get() method that is created is rather unhelpful - it ends up being something like "getElement1AndElement2AndElement3()".

I'd like to rename the get() method to be something better, but I can't figure out exactly how to do that. I know in [the tutorial](https://jaxb.dev.java.net/tutorial/section_5_3-Overriding-Names.html) it describes customizing class names by using  on an element.

I found a really old article (http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/12/10/jaxb.html?page=2) that describes attaching a "name" attribute to a  element, which seems to be what I need to do. Unfortunately, I think that article refers to a 1.x JAXB version, and the name attribute is no longer valid in a choice element as of JAXB 2.0.

So does anybody know how I can customize the method name that gets generated? Please let me know if examples or any other information would be helpful, or if what I'm trying to do just isn't possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so I've figured out where my issue is.  Unlike the example that I linked to, the schema that I am using has the <xjc:simple /> vendor customization enabled.  That is the issue - with the <xjc:simple /> tag in there, I get an error in the customization file.  Without the tag, no problems.

It appears there's a really old bug report (https://jaxb.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=236) that has been filed.  If anyone has any ideas on a workaround (other than removing the simple tag, which causes lots of other issues I'd prefer to avoid), I'd be interested in hearing them!

Comment: I wouldn't go ahead with <xjc:simple> since mentioned in the documentation. "Once again, readers are warned that this is an experimental binding mode"... The 2 bindings are simply not compatible.
I can support with the other issues you're having.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tried with the example exposed in the link you provide and the following binding.xjb works:

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jxb:bindings>
      <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="po4.xsd" node="/xs:schema/xs:element[@name='Widgets']//xs:complexType//xs:choice">
            <jxb:property name="Shapes"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

I use JAXB 2.1.12 as well.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct, it definitely works in the example.  Obviously I'm doing something else wrong.  Thanks for pointing that out to me!