# how to group xsd:elements of an xsd:choice together and outsource them?

Tags: xsd, jaxb

I'm working with XSD and I have a xsd:choice with many xsd:elements in it. Now I want to simplify it a little bit and therefore I've grouped the xsd:elements, so that I can outsource (and reuse) them in separate xsd:elements.

Before:

```
<!-- main.xsd -->
<xsd:element name="account">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element name="login-id" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="login-username" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="login-password" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="login-note" type="xsd:string" />

            <xsd:element name="contact-name" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="contact-address" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="contact-phone" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="contact-note" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

After:

```
<!-- main.xsd -->
<xsd:include schemaLocation="outsourced.xsd" />

<xsd:element name="account">
    <xsd:complexType>
       <xsd:choice>
           <xsd:element ref="login" />

           <xsd:element ref="contact" />
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<!-- outsourced.xsd -->
<xsd:element name="login">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element name="login-id" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="login-username" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="login-password" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="login-note" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="contact">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element name="contact-name" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="contact-address" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="contact-phone" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="contact-note" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Sadly this creates a new Classes 'login' and 'contact' when generating Java-Source from it, what I want to avoid. Is there any way to outsource the grouped xsd:elements to simplify the xsd:choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but it should be one of the following:

- you either want to simplify the name of the generated field so instead of n1n2n3 you get something more readable; in this case I suggest to go with [this solution presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229469/customize-jaxb-2-0-generated-method-names-from-a-xsdchoice-element)
- I suggest you to read Blaise's blog [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-xsd-choice-xmlelements.html) and [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xml-schema-to-java-xsd-choice.html) - it should help understand your solution or at least how to better formulate your question.

UPDATE: Ok, what you need to do is to wrap those two groups of xsd:elements with an xsd:sequence and then play with the bindings file to get what you want (I assume you're using JAXB).

UPDATE 2: So it sounds like you are using JAXB. Then if you take the schema below, I believe it gives you what you want, reuse (by referencing model groups) and no new classes. I'll post both artifacts but I suggest you also try it (I've used NetBeans) to see what's going on (also write a test client in Java that uses the class, look at what a developer will see, etc.)  and if it is still not what you want, use the results of your attempt to illustrate some more your question.

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="account">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:group ref="login"/>
                <xsd:group ref="contact"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:group name="login">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="login-id" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="login-username" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="login-password" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="login-note" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>

    </xsd:group>

    <xsd:group name="contact">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="contact-name" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="contact-address" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="contact-phone" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="contact-note" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:group>
</xsd:schema>
```

Java Generated class (default, no custom bindings, removed irrelevant content):

```
package sequnderchoice;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "loginId",
    "loginUsername",
    "loginPassword",
    "loginNote",
    "contactName",
    "contactAddress",
    "contactPhone",
    "contactNote"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "account")
public class Account {

    @XmlElement(name = "login-id")
    protected String loginId;
    @XmlElement(name = "login-username")
    protected String loginUsername;
    @XmlElement(name = "login-password")
    protected String loginPassword;
    @XmlElement(name = "login-note")
    protected String loginNote;
    @XmlElement(name = "contact-name")
    protected String contactName;
    @XmlElement(name = "contact-address")
    protected String contactAddress;
    @XmlElement(name = "contact-phone")
    protected String contactPhone;
    @XmlElement(name = "contact-note")
    protected String contactNote;

    public String getLoginId() {
        return loginId;
    }

    public void setLoginId(String value) {
        this.loginId = value;
    }

    public String getLoginUsername() {
        return loginUsername;
    }

    public void setLoginUsername(String value) {
        this.loginUsername = value;
    }

    public String getLoginPassword() {
        return loginPassword;
    }

    public void setLoginPassword(String value) {
        this.loginPassword = value;
    }

    public String getLoginNote() {
        return loginNote;
    }

    public void setLoginNote(String value) {
        this.loginNote = value;
    }

    public String getContactName() {
        return contactName;
    }

    public void setContactName(String value) {
        this.contactName = value;
    }

    public String getContactAddress() {
        return contactAddress;
    }

    public void setContactAddress(String value) {
        this.contactAddress = value;
    }

    public String getContactPhone() {
        return contactPhone;
    }

    public void setContactPhone(String value) {
        this.contactPhone = value;
    }

    public String getContactNote() {
        return contactNote;
    }

    public void setContactNote(String value) {
        this.contactNote = value;
    }        
}
```

Comment: Now the question is clarified a bit.

Comment: And that's my problem, I don't know how to do that (exactly).

Comment: Unfortunately, if you want to nicely "tuck" groups of elements, I am not aware of a way without creating a new class. If you're using JAXB, you will need a custom binding file. In principle, I would like it this way as opposed to creating a wrapper element, since it'll keep your XML structure flatter...

Comment: My xsd is quite huge, so this might also lead to an huge binding file which would be difficult to maintain. Am I right with this theory?